# Move cursor to next element on enter keeping track of tabindex

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using following code to move to next element.  Code is working fine except for the tabindex=-1.  It does not skip elements with tabindex set to -1.

```
        $('body').on('keydown', 'input, select', function(e) {
            if (e.key === "Enter") {
                var self = $(this), form = self.parents('form:eq(0)'), focusable, next;
                focusable = form.find('input,a,select,button,textarea').filter(':visible');
                next = focusable.eq(focusable.index(this)+1);
                if (next.length) {
                    next.focus();
                } else {
                    form.submit();
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

I have been searching for the solution but could not find one.
Can anyone please help.

Comment: Can you add the html this code references?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You focus specificly the next element, you don't let the browser handle it. Therefor the tabindex=-1 is not working.

To use the tabindex you specified in the HTML you have to specify it in the Javascript aswell ( `:not([tabindex="-1"])` ) :

```
 focusable = form.find('input,a,select,button,textarea').filter(':not([tabindex="-1"]):visible');
```